# Printing default message if session not set

Tags: php, session

I have a bookstore website that currently has a login feature which sets a session upon successful login. Im trying to implement a header on my index.php file which prints out "Guest" if user is not logged in and replaces "Guest" with their name upon successful login. Currently, when the user logs in I have my webpage print out "Welcome to the Bookstore, (name)". But if the user is not logged in and no session is set it only prints out "Welcome to the Bookstore,". Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";

    $greeting = "";

    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        $greeting = "Guest";
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION)) {
        $greeting = $_SESSION['name'];
    }



 ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>UND Bookstore</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
        <meta name="author" content="Sai Peri"></meta>
        <meta name="description" content="CSCI 457 Assignment 1"></meta>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Latest jQuery libraries -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse text-center">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
                            <li><a href="check.php">Add/Delete/Edit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div> <!-- End col-md-12 -->
            </div>  <!-- End row (nav)-->
            <div class="row" id="body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Welcome to the Bookstore, <?php echo $greeting; ?></h3>
                    </div> <!-- End of page-header -->
                    <p class="text-center">In order to get the full functionalty of the website you need to login. If you do not have an account you can register on the same "Login" webpage. You do not need to be logged in to use the search functionality, however. It should be noted that only the administrator can access the "Add/Delete/Edit" page.</p>
                </div> <!-- End col-md-12 -->
            </div> <!-- End row (nav)-->
            <div class="row" id="footer">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <footer>Created 2019 by Sai Peri</footer>
                </div> <!-- End col-md-12 -->
            </div> <!-- End row (nav)-->
        </div> <!-- End container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to check like this `if(!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']))` .

Comment: @Ishaan is correct, `$_SESSION` will always be there. You need to check a specific index like `$_SESSION['name']` or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, is there even any point in checking to see that a user is not logged in? why not just assume this is the case and add the username to the greeting if one is found.

Something like:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";

    $greeting = "Guest";

    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        $greeting = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['name']);
        // added special chars to avoid xss attacks
    }



 ?>
```